# Firebase Username/Password Authentication - allow only one device to sign-in at a time

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase Username/Password authentication in my Android app.  But it seems to allow any number of devices to sign in using a single username/password.  Is there a way to limit sign-in to a single device (or a limited small number of devices)?

What I am looking for is something like this.  When a new device signs-in using an existing username/password:

```
   a) validate the username and password

   b) sign-out all devices currently signed in with that username/password

   c) then sign-in the new device
```

I saw something about revoking Refresh tokens (https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions) - can this be used to achieve the above?

Alternately, is there a way to limit the number of simultaneous logins?

Right now I am NOT using any databases - **would prefer a solution that does not require use of a database**.

Comment: Firebase authentication uses email/password, how are you adding username?

Comment: @Peter Haddad, using  mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think is it possible without a database, because by default firebase doesn't provide any way to limit or get active sessions for a user. 
What you can do is, after logging in you can maintain the login history of the user for different devices and also logout by revoking refresh tokens for that devices.
[Revoke refresh token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions#revoke_refresh_tokens)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Revoke refresh token

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().revokeRefreshTokens(uid);
```

On revocation, the user is signed out and prompted to reauthenticate.

Comment: Have you done this?  From the app (client) end? Doesn't it revoke the sign-in for the last sign-in as well? Also, this requires Firebase Admin SDK to be used on the app end?  Bit of a security concern.